# Генерация сертификата подписи

Tags: java, x509

Всем привет. Есть алгоритм электронной подписи ГОСТ 34.10, который выдаёт подпись документа. Реализовано на Java. Как мне теперь сгенерировать сертификат в формате x509, чтобы поместить туда эту подпись? Тоже на Java.

Comment: Разве подпись помещается в сертификат? Вроде же всё не так. В сертификате хранится ключ шифрования и название алгоритма. Подпись получается из документа и приватного ключа с помощью алгоритма. Проверяется публичным ключом с помощью алгоритма. Таким образом надо как-то внедрить свой алгоритм в криптографическую инфраструктуру жавы. Может это стандартное  руководство Вам поможет https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html

Answer (score 1):

Вы надеюсь уже готовым криптопровайдером для java пользуетесь? (Что то типа этого [КриптоПро](http://cryptopro.ru/products/csp/jcp))

> Как мне теперь сгенерировать сертификат в формате x509, чтобы поместить туда эту подпись?

Что значит *поместить подпись в сертификат* я тоже не понимаю. Подпись это дополнительная информация которая к документу прикладывается для проверки подлинности, а сертификат это набор правил (открытый ключ, алгоритм, срок действия и т.д.) по которым эту подпись положено проверять. Скорее наоборот в формате CAdEs в подпись дополнительно укладывается сертификат для проверки.

А если у вас уже стоит на jcp провайдер для ГОСТ 34.10, то нет проблем сертификат сохранить:

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("cert.cer");
os.write(Base64.encodeBase64(cert.getEncoded(), true));
os.close();
```

**UPD**

Сертификаты вообще-то *keytool* в java генерить умеет, лишь бы провайдер соответствующий был.

Примерно так:

```
keytool -genkey -alias myGostCert -provider ru.CryptoPro.JCP.JCP -sigalg GOST3411withGOST3410EL -keystore keystore.jks
```

Вот [тут это криптопрошным JCP делают](https://www.cryptopro.ru/cryptopro/forum/view.asp?q=3504), тем провайдером который я выше приводил.  Он там заставит всю информацию необходимую для сертификата передать.
В общем-то можно будет сертификат из хранилища той же утилитой и достать:

```
keytool -export -alias myGostCert -file server.cer -keystore keystore.jks
```

Comment: А можно поподробнее про сохранение сертификата? И ссылочки на примеры, если можно. Я вот не пойму, как сам сертификат собирать. Просто брать всю инфу о пользователе и в файл cert.cer записывать?

Comment: @Cuthbert_Allgood вообще количество информации в сертификате зависит от самого сертификата, кроме того туда ещё и дополнительные параметры можно записывать. Добавил разъяснения в ответ.

Comment: Я могу этот сертификат собрать программно? У меня есть все данные, мне только нужно правильно их записать в файл .cer . Я могу это сделать стандартными средствами java? Не через keytool

Comment: @Cuthbert_Allgood без дополнительного тюнинга JVM нет.
Можете сами провайдер написать, поглядите статью которую привёл banme в комментарии.

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html